# Locate City: where's the origin point?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

What point within the nearby metropolis/town/... are the distances and bearings given by *locate city* referenced to?  Is it the center of the town square, perhaps?  A geometric center-of-population-mass?  Some other sort of computed centroid?

Comment: Shalvenay, what exactly do you want, where will it be, what is the primary function, etc.? There are a lot of questions coming up over similar things. Are you running an Ebberon Campaign?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Whatever the DM says it is**

For some inconceivable reason, the spell's authors didn't rely on the spell being used as a non-narrative navigational aide. Absolutely no mention is made to it's capabilities as a nuke nor to how "population" or "town" is assessed.

This problem, therefore, falls squarely in the DM's prerogative, and the specific details of the spell's instantiation are a function of the game's narrative.

Comment: Fun.  Makes me wonder if I really am the first person to go "hey, this looks like what a VOR/DME gives me..."